# Radio button selected is always on

Tags: javascript, d3.js, radio-button

I create this html page containing 5 radio button:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>

    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col' id='vaccine-selector-container' style='background-color:#FFC300;'>
            <div class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
                <input type='radio' id='rb-dtp' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input' checked>
                <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-dtp' title='Vaccine against diphtheria, tetanus, pertussis'>DTP</label>
            </div>
            <div class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
                <input type='radio' id='rb-mmr' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input'>
                <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-mmr' title='Vaccine against measles, mumps and rubella'>MMR</label>
            </div>      
            <div class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
                <input type='radio' id='rb-pol' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input'>
                <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-pol' title='Vaccine against poliomyelitis' title='Vaccine against poliomyelitis'>POL</label>
            </div>
            <div class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
                <input type='radio' id='rb-hib' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input'>
                <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-hib'>HIB</label>
            </div>  
            <div class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
                <input type='radio' id='rb-hepB' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input'>
                <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-hepB' title='Vaccine against hepatitis b'>HEP B</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='col' id='showCasesOrNotDivId' style='background-color:#FF5733;'>
        </div>
    </div> 

</div>
```

Now I'm trying to print what radio button is selected when user change selection.

```
var vaccineSelected = 'DTP';
d3.selectAll('input[name=vaccine-selector]').on('change', function() {
    vaccineSelected = this.value;
    console.log('vaccineSelected:', vaccineSelected); // on
});
```

Entire code [**HERE**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XpwAHjedjFiHuEddSfk7?preview&p=preview).

The result I get is always `on`. Why? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputs don't set a `value` attribute and as [MDN puts it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio#Data_representation_of_a_radio_group):

> If you omit the value attribute in the HTML, the submitted form data
>   assigns the value "on" to the group.

Either set a `value` attribute :

```
<input type='radio' id='rb-dtp' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom- control-input' 
    value='DTP'
>
```

Or read a different attribute, for example `id`:

```js
d3.selectAll('input[name=vaccine-selector]').on('change', function() {
    vaccineSelected = this.id;
    console.log('vaccineSelected:', vaccineSelected); // on
});
```